# Joomla 1.5 to 2.5 : JLIB_APPLICATION_ERROR_VIEW_NOT_FOUND

Tags: php, apache

I migrated from Joomla 1.5 to Joomla 2.5 with jUpgrade. Re-installed several components with 2.5 versions, migrated Joomfish, etc...

At first I had troubles getting the rewriting to work (SEF and rewriting enabled, htaccess well configured), homepage displaying OK but Joomfish URLs getting to 404 with Rewriting (working OK with only SEF enabled so URL of that kind : /index.php/fr/page instead of /fr/page).

Then I don't know what happened, but I get an error 500 on every front end page. The Backend is still working OK. Tried to switch components off, switch template, turn  SEF and rewriting OFF, I always get the same thing :

```
Affichage introuvable [name, type, prefix] : frontpage, html, contentView

Si les difficultés persistent, merci de contacter l'administrateur de ce site.

Call stack
#   Function    Location
1   JSite->dispatch()   /Users/guylabbe/Dropbox/bckup/Permanent/_WebProjekte/capacoa2/index.php:42
2   JComponentHelper::renderComponent() /Users/guylabbe/Dropbox/bckup/Permanent/_WebProjekte/capacoa2/includes/application.php:197
3   JComponentHelper::executeComponent()    /Users/guylabbe/Dropbox/bckup/Permanent/_WebProjekte/capacoa2/libraries/joomla/application/component/helper.php:351
4   require_once()  /Users/guylabbe/Dropbox/bckup/Permanent/_WebProjekte/capacoa2/libraries/joomla/application/component/helper.php:383
5   JController->execute()  /Users/guylabbe/Dropbox/bckup/Permanent/_WebProjekte/capacoa2/components/com_content/content.php:16
6   ContentController->display()    /Users/guylabbe/Dropbox/bckup/Permanent/_WebProjekte/capacoa2/libraries/joomla/application/component/controller.php:761
7   JController->display()  /Users/guylabbe/Dropbox/bckup/Permanent/_WebProjekte/capacoa2/components/com_content/controller.php:74
8   JController->getView()  /Users/guylabbe/Dropbox/bckup/Permanent/_WebProjekte/capacoa2/libraries/joomla/application/component/controller.php:677
9   JError::raiseError()    /Users/guylabbe/Dropbox/bckup/Permanent/_WebProjekte/capacoa2/libraries/joomla/application/component/controller.php:903
10  JError::raise() /Users/guylabbe/Dropbox/bckup/Permanent/_WebProjekte/capacoa2/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:251
```

Error #7 triggered by :

```
    $view = $this->getView($viewName, $viewType, '', array('base_path' => $this->basePath, 'layout' => $viewLayout));
```

Error #8 triggered by :

```
$result = JError::raiseError(500, JText::sprintf('JLIB_APPLICATION_ERROR_VIEW_NOT_FOUND', $name, $type, $prefix));
```

any idea?

Comment: Does the url you're trying to hit have a cooresponding view in that component's views folder?

Comment: @ContextSwitch : Thank you for your help. I'm not sure, but anyway, I switched themes to default J2.5 ones, (beez, atomic) and I am still getting this error so I guess this is not template-related, right?

Answer (score 1):

This appeared to be an error due to JoomFish Component. My lang was switched to the translated language (without knowing) and causing Error 500 (that I could solve by re-maping better migrated data in database, eww)... If I cleared my cookies, I would get the default language and the Error 500 would be gone ...

Also, as I migrated from jUpgrade, that copies migrated files in a subfolder of the initial Joomla install, I think I had some rules from the initial htaccess file interfering with the new one.